# Is there a way to watch all .graphql file extensions while running jest --watch?

Tags: graphql, jestjs

I'm using `graphql-import` in my schema tests running on Jest.

*schema.test.js:*

```
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import');
const typeDefs = importSchema('./src/schema/types/schema.graphql');
```

*types/schema.graphql:*

```
# import Provider, Query.* from 'provider.graphql'
# import Agreement, Query.* from 'agreement.graphql'

scalar DateTime

type Query {
  hello: String
  count: Int
}
```

When I run the tests with `jest --watch`, Jest doesn't recognise when I modify one of the leaf .graphql files (e.g. provider.graphql). Presumably, this is because `graphql-import` uses its own import syntax.

Is there any way to tell Jest to watch all .graphql files for modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the root of your project, you can add a [`jest.config.js`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration). Here you can provide what extensions your project depends on, using prop `moduleFileExtensions` By default its `["js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node"]`

Comment: tested that this works, despite the somewhat misleading documentation for what moduleFileExtensions is for.